# jQuery autocomplete only displays results sometimes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-2, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete on a textbox, but it only works some of the time and I can't figure out why. The method I tell it to call returns a Json object that is a list of peoples names that it retrieves from active directory. For some reason the autocomplete won't display them after the user types in three or more characters, even if the search returns a list of names.

The code in the view is like this:

```
<input type="text" id="nominee_name" />
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#nominee_name').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/cap/findnames", type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                    data: { searchText: request.term, maxResults: 10 },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.FullName, value: item.FullName, id: item.FullName }
                        }))
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

So for example, typing "Da" will display a bunch of Dave's in the autocomplete box, but typing "Dave" will display nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure `/cap/findnames` returns something when the search term is `dave`?

Comment: Install getfirebug.com and when you type a letter you can see the exact query you're making to the page and response it sends back

Comment: yeah, that was the first thing I checked :)